# In $\mathbb{Q}$ is every $F_\sigma$ set also a $ G_\delta $ set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, set-theory

As we know, In a topological space, $F_\sigma$ sets are the countable union of closed sets, and $G_\delta$ sets are the countable intersection of open sets. Here, in this problem, we are considering the usual topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. induced topology from $\mathbb{R}$).

$\mathbb{Q}$ is a metric space, and I know the proof of,

1. Every closed set in a metric space is a $G_\delta$ set.
2. Finite union of $G_\delta$ set is a $G_\delta$ set.

Therefore, in the case of space $\mathbb{Q}$, can we generalise the 2nd statement to get  "the countable union of $G_\delta$ sets is a $G_\delta$ set?" If not, is there any other way to prove it?

Comment: Any subset $E \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is both $F_{\sigma}$-set and $G_{\delta}$-set because $$ E = \cup_{r\in E}\{r\} = \cap_{r \in \mathbb{Q}\setminus E} (\mathbb{Q} \setminus\{r\}) $$ and each $\mathbb{Q} \setminus\{r\}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As Sangchul Lee points out in their comment, every subset of $\mathbb Q$ is both $G_\delta$ and $F_\sigma$. In fact for any countable $T_1$ space $X$ and $A\subseteq X$ we have

$$A=\bigcup\{\{x\}:x\in A\}=\bigcap\{X\setminus\{x\}:x\in X\setminus A\}$$

with $\{x\}$ closed and $X\setminus\{x\}$ open.